# Domain-wide installation of a Chrome Extension with OAuth2 authorizations for Google APIs

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

I'm developing a Chrome extension, addressed to GMail users only, which needs access to some Google APIs. I use OAuth2 for authentication and authorization.

Wanting to help Google Apps domain administrators deliver the product to all users in their domain with minimal work, I have registered a project in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and published it (privately, as yet) to the Google Apps Marketplace.

The extension itself is already published in the Chrome Web Store.

With this, domain administrators can, from their Admin Console:

(a) Go to "Apps > Marketplace apps" and add our app for all users in the domain.

or

(b) Go to "Apps > Device Management > Chrome Management > User Settings" and add our extension to the "Forced-installed Apps and Extensions".

If they do (a), users who install the Chrome Extension get "one-click single-sign-on": once they authenticate to our app, they won't need to approve any permissions.

If they do (b), users get our Chrome Extension automagically installed in their Chrome browser, but they still need to approve permissions after their first authentication.

If administrators do both (a) and (b), users get the same result as if they did only (b) -- that is: users still need to approve permissions.

Is it possible to get both? That is: have the extension force-installed and the authorizations granted by the administrator?

How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the Google Apps Marketplace only supports hosted applications, not extensions or packaged apps. I don't think it would be possible to accomplish what you want, at least not without two different installations.